# Custom ckEditor Toolbar in Liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-6.2

I want to add my own custom toolbar for my ckeditor and have therefore added this to my `ckconfig.jsp` via a hook.

```
config.toolbar_Mini = [
    ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike'],
    ['BulletedList']
];
```

Additionally I've found out that liferay uses the `config.toolbar_liferay`settings. How (**code**) and where (**file**) can I change this default behaviour?

**EDIT:**
This is how the html-editor for my journal-articles looks now:[image: status now]

and I want to limit the functionality of the toolbar to this:
[image: Result]

I do not want to change the default `config.toolbar_liferay` toolbar because I might need a different toolbar later on.
Is this the correct way to achieve this (via hook?) or can I just add a new completely new ckeditor that can be used in a structure?

Comment: Have you modified ckconfig.jsp using plugin-hook?

Comment: yes, but no result

Comment: can you provide more information on what you tried and what you want to achieve?

Comment: @PankajkumarKathiriya see the edit in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Below configuration settings represents configuration for journal article ck-editor screen.
From ckconfig.jsp of source code.

`config.toolbar_liferayArticle = [
        ['Styles', 'FontSize', '-', 'TextColor', 'BGColor'],
        ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike'],
        ['Subscript', 'Superscript'],
        '/',
        ['Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'SelectAll', 'RemoveFormat'],
        ['Find', 'Replace', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt'],
        ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote'],
        ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
        '/',
        ['Source'],
        ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'],
        ['Image', 'Flash', <c:if test="<%= XugglerUtil.isEnabled() %>">'Audio', 'Video',</c:if> 'Table', '-', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'LiferayPageBreak']
    ];`

So, if you want to have different configuration setting for CKEditor of journal-article then you have to modify config.toolbar_liferayArticle in ckconfig.jsp using liferay plugin hook.

e.g
`config.toolbar_liferayArticle=[
    ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike'],
    ['BulletedList']
];`

Comment: I have done so but this has absolutely no effect. I tried many times and the only one that is working is the `config.toolbar_liferay`. Also I don't want to change it because I might need a different one for other articles.

Comment: Well, in that case your hook may not be getting deployed properly. To debug you may look into actual files under tomcat/webapps/ROOT/html/js to make sure your changes are getting affected.

Comment: The hook is getting deployed correctly as I can see the changes I have done in my hook. As said before, only the changes to the `config.toolbar_liferay` have an effect on the ckeditor.